# Delete from NodeSet during map iteration?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Is it safe to delete a Node from a NodeSet during iteration? I'm pulling some links out of a bunch of a tags but want to remove the tags from the set altogether if the link is invalid.

```
def get_links(nodeset)
  links = nodeset.map do |node|
    begin
      URI.join(node.document.url, node.get_attribute('href'))
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      nodeset.delete(node) # Is this safe?
      nil
    end
  end
  links.compact
end
```

Comment: if you are iterating over a list it is wrong to delete elements in the list to prevent unexpected before, instead use a clone of the list and delete elements from the clone, and swap the list with the clone after the iteration

Comment: What have you tried? Start with a small XML input sample and try it. Look at the DOM after you're finished to see what happened.

Comment: I'm not deleting from the DOM, only from the NodeSet. I'm not trying to modify the document at all, just collect information from it. But I have to iterate over this NodeSet later and it saves time if I don't have to detect which nodes are valid later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code I think you're not separating your actions well. Don't manipulate your `nodeset` array inside the `map`; It's not that you *can't* do it, it's that you *shouldn't* for clarity and ease of maintenance. "Map" the URLs separately from removing the bad ones.

At a minimum I'd do something more like:

```
def get_valid_links(nodeset)
  doc_url = nodeset.first.document.url
  links = nodeset.map { |node|
    begin
      URI.join(doc_url, node['href'])
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      nil
    end
  end
  links.compact
end

nodeset = get_valid_links(nodeset)
```

Doing it that way doesn't alter `nodeset` unless you explicitly say so, by assigning the compacted/mapped value returned from `get_links`. That keeps the purpose of the method very clear, and it has no side effects.

I think this is one of those cases where "POLS" ("Principle Of Least Surprise") would kick in. Having the side-effect of munging `nodeset` inside the method *could* be very surprising to someone who's trying to maintain the code or use it in a library, and it'd be hard to work around.

From experience, I'll recommend being very careful throwing the contents of `href` attributes onto the end of a URL and expecting it to be good or useful. Remember that it's possible for the `href` to be a JavaScript link, which will make an ugly URL.